# How to update table 2 from the inserted data in table 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help me on what query I to to update one table with data from another.

I have 2 tables for example:

tbl_med_take

```
| id | name |   med  | qty |
---------------------------------
| 1 | jayson | med2 |  3   |
| 2 |   may   | med2 |  4   |
| 3 | jenny.  | med3 |  6   |
| 4 |   joel.   | med3 |  4   |
```

tbl_med

```
| id | med | stocks |
-----------------------------
| 1 | med1 |    20    |
| 2 | med2 |.   17    |
| 3 | med3 |    24    |
```

The output that I want in tbl_med:

tbl_med

```
| id | med | stocks |
-----------------------------
| 1 | med1 |    20    |
| 2 | med2 |.   10    |
| 3 | med3 |    14    |
```

Comment: If you want tbl_med to reflect all tbl_med_take updates, you need a trigger based solution.

Comment: Sorry, I using SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the total consumed from `med_tbl_take` using

```
select med,sum(quantity) as total from tbl_med_take group by med
```

Then you can `left join` with your `med_tbl` and subtract.

```
select m.id,m.med,(m.stocks-ISNULL(n.total,0)) from tbl_med m 
left join
(select med,sum(quantity) as total from tbl_med_take group by med) n
on m.med=n.med
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=86c76ab1baddb64339fbf909df656148)

Comment: @LenardAllila  Glad i could help :) please mark this as accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help. God bless.